# How can I detect the memory data changed?

Tags: c, windows, security

I am studying about the windows programming, and i have some question.

I saw a security module that defends memory data.
if one process is going to change other process memory, it detects and turns off the process.

This is often used in anti-cheat engines in games or bank application programs(i live in Korea, so i think this is the best example of this. Almost every on-line games or bank application has self-defence algorithm.)

My question is, **is there any APIs or functions that detects about this?**

thanks.

P.S.
i can make an example,

if **0x01000000** memory data is **'A'**, some different process changed it to **'B'**.
when i first thought about this, i thought that i have to make a thread to check the data and if it changes, turn off the process.
but i think this is not a good idea. any suggestions?

Comment: Are you detecting across other applications or your own (i.e. is this purely internal functionality, or used for the whole OS)? You cannot directly access any other application's memory easily due to virtual memory, however, it can be done.

Comment: @Nagi: no modern OS (including Windows) will allow one process to change another one's memory. Which security module are you talking about?

Comment: @IgorKorkhov: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681674%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @Igor Korhkov: Sure they do, if you allow it. After all your debugger manages it somehow. Completely protecting your program from a user doing "bad things" to it while running on a machine he controls is virtually impossible, usually ending up with an ongoing arms-race between the hackers/cheaters and the application programmers.

Comment: @SLaks, doynax: Sure I know about debuggers, kernel drivers, special API, and hardware debugger boards. I just wanted to clarify the level of protection required.

Comment: @IgorKorkhov, SLaks: thanks for comments. Well, i am not a hacker and i just enjoy studying securities and Windows Programming. WriteProcessMemory and ReadProcessMemory function needs special function to unprotect memory(such as VirtualProtectEx Function). If there is no secure services, no virus alerts, logged in as a administrator account, etc(i just wanna say, there is nothing to defend it.). can I detect it?

Comment: @Nagi: I don't think it's an easy task anyway. You can theoretically scan another process' memory, but don't forget that while your monitoring thread is waiting for its next turn to run again after context switching, the memory data can be changed thousand times and restored to its original state, so you'll never be able to detect such changes. The only *reliable* way that I can think of is to use x86 debug registers. You can start from reading this tiny Wikipedia article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_debug_register and then Google helps you to find another resources.

Answer (score 2):

General answer to your question: no, there are no such API or functions.

But there are different methods where you can achieve same result.
1. Api hooking. You can Hook functions in system (such as WriteProcessMemory) and then check if somebody trying to change something in your process. More on this [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/hooksys.aspx).
2. Debugging. You can use debugging breakpoints on functions or memory change.

Answer (score 1):

There's [an API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-getwritewatch) that allows you to monitor writing operations into a piece of the specific memory area.

```
UINT GetWriteWatch(
  DWORD     dwFlags,
  PVOID     lpBaseAddress,
  SIZE_T    dwRegionSize,
  PVOID     *lpAddresses,
  ULONG_PTR *lpdwCount,
  LPDWORD   lpdwGranularity
);
```

When the API detects any writing operations, it appends the writing addresses into the arrays that you provided as the parameter of the API, until your array is full.